# Can't see the Boats appearing - Step 4

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css, aura

It little strange. I passed the lightning component framework specialist step 4 - which is about implementing the search functionality of showing the boats in tiles. I passed the challenge but I do not see the boats properly. I followed the instructions of using CSS clearly but still don't see it. ( May be I am using it incorrectly?). I do see in my console how many boats are returned when ever I click on the search button. The result matches with how many boats are present in the system. Any clue how I can resolve this?

BoatTile.cmp

```
<aura:component >
<aura:attribute name="boat" type="Boat__c" description="" />
<lightning:button class="title">
<div style="{!'background-image:url('+v.boat.Picture__c+')'}" class="innertile">
  <div class="lower-third">
   <h1 class="slds-truncate">{!v.boat.Contact__r.name}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
</lightning:button> 
</aura:component>
```

Css of the above:

```
.THIS {
}

.THIS.tile {
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
    padding: 1px !important;
}

.THIS .innertile {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.THIS .lower-third {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    padding: 6px 8px;
}
```

This is how I see the boats appearing on my search:

[image]

BoatSearchResults.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="BoatSearchResults">
    <aura:attribute name="boats" type="Boat__c[]" description="" />
    <aura:attribute name="message" type="String" description="" />
    <aura:attribute name="boatTypeId" type="String" description="" />
    <aura:method name="search"
      description="search boats">
        <aura:attribute name="boatTypeId" type="Id" />
    </aura:method>

<lightning:layout horizontalAlign="center" multipleRows="true">
  <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.boats))}"> 
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.boats}" var="aBoat">
      <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="grow" class="slds-m-right_small" >
        <c:BoatTile boat="{!aBoat}"/>   
      </lightning:layoutItem>   
    </aura:iteration>
    <aura:set attribute="else">
     <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
            No boats found
     </div>     
    </aura:set>
  </aura:if>
</lightning:layout>     
</aura:component>
```

Comment: with your browser dev tools,  you can check if the resources are loading correctly

Comment: And please remove any reference of superbadges in your post, thanks!

Comment: I have added a screen shot of the page element. I see .cBoatTile .lower-third. Does it look correct to you? Not sure what to check here.

Comment: There is a network tab that displays al resources when your page loads, you can google the subject to learn how to use it. When your page loads, you should see your image references load with a status code indicating the reason why they are not displayed if any

Comment: I see the status code as 200. Thanks! Wondering if it is the css style which is not correct or does the syntax I use to get background image is that correct -
 "{!'background-image:url('+v.boat.Picture__c+')'}" Any idea?

Comment: @glls there was some problem with the css used in trailhead. I tried with other css which worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nice, glad you were able to resolve

Answer (score 1):

Below Styling fixed the problem:

```
.THIS.tile {
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 190px;
    height: 220px;
    padding: 1px !important;
}

.THIS .innertile {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 150px;
    height: 180px;

}

.THIS .lower-third {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    padding: 6px 8px;
}
```